# How to count messages in the window message queue?

Tags: winapi, message-queue

It seems that there's no a documented API to accomplish the subj, but maybe there's an undocumented one, or some trick to do this?

Comment: No tricks to achieve this. Perhaps you can tell us what motivates the question. Basically there's no API for this because you don't need to do it.

Comment: I have to agree with @DavidHeffernan here.  Whatever you problem is with this WMQ, find another way of solving it that does not involve counting the messages.  Even if there was an undocumented call to get this count, it might not work on other, or subsequent, Windows versions.

Comment: I need this :) We have a case where degenerate user code can cause the queue to fill up with messages and thus crash the application. We need to find a way to throttle the user messages while still allowing our application messages through (and of course not crash). It would be nice to know how full the queue is or at least if messages are being queued faster than windows can process them.

Comment: I personally could use this, because we've been forced by management to use someone else's badly behaving component that floods our message queue.  I need to gather evidence for how bad it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only two counts you can get are "full" (something like `PostMessage` fails with the error `ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_QUOTA`) and "empty" (`PeekMessage` returns zero).

If you need any other value, you're probably trying to solve the wrong problem.

Comment: While I agree that no reasonable application should care during normal runtime, it would be useful to know for debugging and performance analysis.